# Docker прерывает установку пакетов pip на одном и том же месте

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip

Пробую запустить docker-compose и постоянно падает на установке одного и того же пакета. При чем еще пару недель назад работат над проектом и все работало хорошо.

Ошибка такая:

```
#17 174.5   Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
#17 177.5 Collecting termcolor==1.1.0
#17 179.4   Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
#17 180.7 Collecting threadpoolctl==2.1.0
#17 180.7   Downloading threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
#17 181.3 Collecting tokenizers==0.10.2
#17 181.4   Downloading tokenizers-0.10.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
#17 184.6 Collecting torch==1.8.1
#17 185.9   Downloading torch-1.8.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (804.1 MB)
#17 281.1 Killed
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 137
```

Ну, сам докер-файл, если интересно, то такой:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7

# clean and update sources
RUN apt-get update -y
# Install some basic utilities
RUN apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Create a working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/bsg_antispamp
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/bsg_antispam

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /usr/src/bsg_antispam
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader stopwords

# copy project
COPY . .
```

Comment: `804.1 MB` — видимо, не хватает оперативки работать с таким большим файлом

Comment: `exit code: 137` это out of memory

Comment: Офтоп. `Create a non-root user and switch to it` - но вы же выдаете этому пользователю рут права, это так и задумано?

Comment: Нет, я не хотел давать этому пользователю рут права. А это ограничить? Как понизить права? Не совсем круто разбираюсь в Линуксе, но идея в том, чтобы повысить безопасность и не давать рут права даже внутри докера

Comment: У меня Мак Про 16. Странно, что не хватает памяти. Пробовал увеличить в настройках Докера - не помогает.

Comment: просто не ставить `sudo` и ничего не добавлять в `/etc/sudoers.d`, тогда у вас будет обычный пользователь (который через `sudo` не сможет ничего сделать) и от его имени будет работать приложение

Comment: Получается так?

# Install some basic utilities
RUN apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /usr/src/bsg_antispam
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user